# Releasing XASession XAResource - Manual enlisting

Tags: weblogic

In our MDB we have a Xatransaction between DB and Tibco foreign server Queue. we have enlisted the foreign server XaResouce using below.

The MDB is on Weblogic server 10.3.6, JDK 1.6.

```
init()---
        XAConnection tempXAConn = xaConn;

        TibjmsXAConnectionFactory xaConnFactory = (TibjmsXAConnectionFactory)ServiceLocator.getInstance().getJNDIReferencedObject(JMS_Q_CONNECTION_FACTORY_JNDI_XA);

       xaConn = xaConnFactory.createXAConnection(JMS_USER,JMS_PSWD);

getsession()---
XASession xaSession = xaConn.createXASession();
TransactionHelper txHelper = TransactionHelper.popTransactionHelper();
Transaction tx = txHelper.getTransaction();
tx.enlistResource(xaSession.getXAResource());
```

Transactions are working fine. we are using one connection and create new xasession for every message.

but the problem is releasing resources. after few thousand msgs i see heap containing same number of Tibjmsxasession,Tibjmsxaresource,Tibjmslongkey objects. this leads to outofmemory issue.

we cannot use session.close() in between the transaction.

The transaction are container managed. only enlisting is done manually.

Answer (score 0):

i used

tx.registerSynchronization(new SessionSynchronization());

SessionSynchronization implements Synchronization and has 2 methods afterCompletion and beforeCompletion.

session.close can be called inside afterCompletion. session can be maintained in threadlocal.